# typescript declaring interface that extends Map for preserving the key order

Tags: typescript

since the normal object doesn't preserve the key order in typescript, I was told to use Map. However I have troubles finding out how to set the values after I have declared the interface.
Here is my attempt:
[Coding](https://codesandbox.io/s/tvqnl)

Comment: A [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) already preserves key order.  What specifically are you trying to do here? The example code should be in the text of the question, and it's confusing that you accepted an answer that did not address your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use such constructor you need to create class, since Map constructor signature is different:

```
class MyMap extends Map<string, any> {  
    public coding: string;
    public 1: number;
    constructor(src: Partial<MyMap>){
      super();
      Object.assign(this, src);      
    }
}

const lol: MyMap = new MyMap({
  coding:"2323",
  1:123
});
```

Comment: okay thx for that, even if this is not solving my issue i will take that as answer. I think typescript is limited in that way, since interfaces are getting lost to runtime.